# Animar fa fa-angle-double-down

Tags: bootstrap-glyphicons

Olá, estou tentando animar este "cara" aqui:

```
fa fa-angle-double-down
```

pois, muitos usuários não percebem que eu quero que ele seja clicado para colapsar mais infos.

Se fosse outro cara, eu faria assim:

```
<li><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>as bullets</li>
```

Comment: Vc que ele pescando ou o que?

Comment: minha ideia é que ele ficasse "tipo animado apontando para baixo sem parar", ou seja, indicando que a pessoa precisa clicá-lo para ver mais infos.

Comment: Jovem só pra constar dei uma atualizada no código da resposta, agora ele fica apontando pra baixo sem parar, acho que pode ser mais próximo do que vc queria.

Comment: Opa. obrigado.Vou testar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara aqui tem um exemplo simples usando @keyframes vc pode ler mais sobre animação com CSS nessa [documentação da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Veja o exemplo:

```css
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
.fa.icone {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: anima 1s ease infinite;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.5rem;
    top: -0.5rem;
}
@keyframes anima {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0.1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down icone"></i> as bullets</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: exato, atende a necessidade. Obrigado pela resposta. Me esforcei nessa pesquisa, mas não tinha encontrado essa solução.

Comment: legal que te serviu. dentro do @keyframes vc pode customizar todo o css da sua animação. Vale a pena dar uma olhadinha no link da documentação!

Comment: Vou ver sim. waleu.

Comment: @Daniel Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Comment: claro, com certeza. já fiz.

Comment: @Daniel valeu meu jovem! Qualquer outra dúvida é só falar, tmj!